# Dispose static variable on page reload or use something else

Tags: c#, performance, inheritance

I don't usually code C#, when i do, i suck

I have parent Class and two derived class. both derived class share an expensive calculation which slightly differ for second one. I am trying to avoid calculate one. 
However, i want

```
interface ICalculator 
{
    double getValue(int id);
    void setContext(int c);
}

abstract class CalculatorBase: ICalculator
{
    internal static Dictionary<int, double> output = null;

    internal void loadData()
    {
        //load data
    }

    internal computeAll()
    {
        //do expenseive calculation and set output
        output = something
    }

    double abstract getValue(int id);
    void abstract setContext(int c);
}

class ChildCalculator1 : CalculatorBase 
{
    override void setContext(int c)
    {
         if (output !=null)
             return;
         loadData();
         computeAll();
    }

    public ovverride getValue(int id)
    {
          return output[id];
    }
}

class ChildCalculator2 : CalculatorBase 
{
    override void setContext(int c)
    {
        if (output !=null)
            return;
         loadData();
         computeAll();
    }

    public ovverride getValue(int id)
    {
        return output[id] -1;
    }
}
```

requirements:

1. if ChildCalculator1 or ChildCalculator or both (one after another) is called, computeAll will be computed once.
2. However, if you reload this page i want to calculate once. This means i want to calculate once every pageload

Question: How can i access parent properties (output) from two different child instance (ChildCalculator1, ChildCalculator) and if you reload the page, that proproperty (output) will be recalculated? Currently I made output as static but this doesnt change when i reload the page.

Static variable might not be the right thing as they survive through out the application not page load. How can i dispose after pageload is done or anything else you can suggest?

Comment: What is your question?  You want to know how to dispose after pageload but you don't show the page code?  How can we help then?

Comment: Thank you for your time. question is: How can i access parent properties (output) from two different child instance (ChildCalculator1, ChildCalculator) and if you reload the page, that proproperty (output) will be recalculated? Currently I made output as static but this doesnt change when i reload the page.

Comment: `static`s are evil, can cause severe performance degradation, and are about as anti-thread-safe as you can get.

Comment: static's are a tool.  How can a tool be evil?  That being said some tools are easier to hurt yourself with than others... so you have to be careful when using static's.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't so bad...  but it could definitely be better.  :)

You are correct that the static dictionary will not get garbage collected.  (In C# the Garbage Collector free's unused memory)  You need all instances of calculator to share your dictionary and you want to dispose of it when you are done.  You could implement a little factory that builds the calculators and gives them all a single instance of the dictionary.  A very simple way to do this however is just to manually manage the static dictionary.

If you add the following method in `CalculatorBase`

```
public static void DoneWithCalculations()
{
    // By removing your static reference to your dictionary you
    //  allow the GC to free the memory.
    output = null;
}
```

You can then call this static method when you are all done with your calculators (for instance at the end of PageLoad) like so...

```
    CalculatorBase.DoneWithCalculations();
```

This will do what you need and doesn't force you to work in C# more than you have to.  :)

Comment: Actually i started doing similar one. but problem with this approach is, i have to call it explicitly.

Comment: @KhanSharp do you only need this during PageLoad?  If so this can be simplified.

Comment: this could be done either at the time of page load or could be when calculation is doen

Comment: So you really can't dispose of output then?  You need to cache it for anytime in the future that you might use it again?